# Using princexml tool from application server on AIX

Tags: java, web-applications, pdf-generation, aix, princexml

Java based Web application I'm working on is deployed on IBM Websphere (WAS 8.5) running on AIX server. Wep app is dependent on using PrinceXML tool for generating PDFs out of html and css. Prince does not have AIX binaries.

Any suggestions to workaround this?

Comment: @KevinBrown - Please read the question. No one is asking for a recommendation on a tool. I have asked if anyone has found a workaround to this or similar issue. Perhaps, an Unix expert would just be knowing on top of his head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested  :

We went with a java based tool called [PDFreactor](http://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/). It runs on JVM so meets our requirement to deploy on AIX.

CSS support is comparable to PrinceXML tool.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you setup (or use an existing) webservice for the PrinceXML end of things.

DocRaptor is a service that uses PrinceXML for HTML to PDF generation: https://docraptor.com/

Or you could setup a simple inside-the-firewall webservice (running on something that is not AIX) that takes in HTML and pipes it to PrinceXML, and spits back a finished PDF.

You may also want to look into getting the open-source `wkhtmltopdf` (http://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to compile on AIX, if you need PDF generation, but not married to PrinceXML for doing so. (Though I cannot find anywhere in a cursory google search that has done it, so I'm not sure if it is possible).